# Adding a boolean value to a 'select new' Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to add a boolean value (`InStock`) to a Linq query, where it sets a value based on a conditional, but I'm getting an error:

`The name 'Any' does not exist in the current context. Cannot resolve symbol 'Any1'`.

Not sure what the proper syntax is here?

```
var query = from o in Orders
            join i in OrderItems on o.SKU equals i.SKU
            where o.OrderId == orderId
            select new OrderObject
            {
                Id = o.OrderId,
                WarehouseQty = i.AvailableQty,
                Sku = i.Sku,
                InStock = Any(x => x.AvailableQty > 0)  //<--need to assign boolean here

            };
```

Comment: Well what are you expecting that "Any" to do? You're in the context where you've got a *single* order item and a *single* order.

Comment: If the `AvailableQty` is > 0, then set `InStock` to `true`.

Comment: Like `InStock = i.AvailableQty > 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the AvailableQty is > 0, then set InStock to true

Well, then use

```
var query = from o in Orders
            join i in OrderItems on o.SKU equals i.SKU
            where o.OrderId == orderId
            select new OrderObject
            {
                Id = o.OrderId,
                WarehouseQty = i.AvailableQty,
                Sku = i.Sku,
                InStock = i.AvailableQty > 0
            };
```

No need to use `Enumerable.Any` which is used to search other collections.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use `InStock = i.AvailableQty > 0`, like this:

```
var query = from o in Orders
            join i in OrderItems on o.SKU equals i.SKU
            where o.OrderId == orderId
            select new OrderObject
            {
                Id = o.OrderId,
                WarehouseQty = i.AvailableQty,
                Sku = i.Sku,
                InStock = i.AvailableQty > 0
            };
```

However, it seems redundant having this *and* the `WarehouseQty` property. Why not just add a readonly property to your class:

```
public class OrderObject
{
    //snip

    public bool InStock => WarehouseQty > 0;
}
```